# Custom Validation Attributes for Array Type Form Fields using proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jsvalidation

I am creating a CRUD using dimsav translatable and proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation packages for Laravel.
The form field names have to follow an array structure like this...

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label("es[title]", trans("messages.title"), ["class" => "control-label"]) !!}
    {!! Form::text("es[title]", getFormInput($entry, "title", $locale), ["class" => "form-control", "id" => "es[title]"]) !!}
</div>
```

To be able to use mass asignment easily on the controller.

The create form is being validated with a CreateRequest as follows...

```
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
         return [
             'es.title' => 'required|max:255',           
         ];
    }
}
```

I don't know how to change the attribute placeholders with more friendly texts at resources/lang/validation.php file. I have tried the following options...

```
'attributes' => [      
    'title' => 'título',
    //'es.title' => 'título',       
    //'es[title]' => 'título',       
],
```

...but any of them is working. The form is being validated ok naming the field 'es.title' but the error message showed is not replacing the field name correctly even if I name the attributes array key also 'es.title'. Any ideas?

Comment: I think proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation is not a good package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `App/Http/Requests/YourRequest`

```
public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'es.title.required' => 'You forgot título!',
        ];
    }
```

You can set different messages for different validation rules(required,max etc)

For setting up custom name for an attribute

```
public function attributes()
{
    return [
        'es.title' => 'título'
    ];
}
```

**EDITED**
For setting up attribute name globally go to `lang/en/validation` and you'll see an attribute array. Change it according to you requirement.

```
'attributes' => [
    'es' => [
        'title' => 'título'
    ]
],
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I wanted. I want to be able to change the field name on the attributes array for each validation.php.

Comment: @HarleyFuagras updated my answer. please check and see if it works.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was trying and it's not working. You can see it in the last piece of code of my question.

Comment: sorry my bad. posted wrong code. Updated again. Please check now